# How to separate third party library CSS from custom CSS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, css-selectors

My front-end designer has added a third party library (in this case bootstrap) into the main.css file, which includes his custom code for our app.

I’ve asked him going forward not to copy and paste 3rd party CSS libraries into custom css. We have about 14K lines of CSS in the main.css. However most of the code is actually Boostrap code. When Rails create asset packages it throws ugly exception. Not sure how to fix that.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any information on the error?

Can you just use a CDN for Bootstrap instead of compiling it?

Comment: You should use CDN and remeber to put the main.css below the bootstrap link in your HTML code.